# JQuery show() does not work for iframe in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, frames

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="createDIV('thediv')">Create DIV</a><br/>
<a href="#" onClick="hideDIV()">Hide Div</a><br/>
<a href="#" onClick="showDIV('thediv')">Show Div</a><br/>
```

And the following 3 JQuery functions to create the DIV, hide it and show it back again:

```
function createDIV(winname)
{
    $('<div id="'+winname+'"></div>').appendTo('body');
$('#'+winname).html('<iframe     src="http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html"     seamless="seamless"></iframe>');
}

function hideDIV()
{
    $("div:visible").hide();
}

function showDIV(winname)
{
    $('#'+winname).show();
}
```

This code works just fine with Chrome and Firefox but, the showDIV function does not work under IE 10.

I noticed it does not work under IE when the iframe src contains a page with frames!

Please, does anyone have a solution or workaround for this? It is driving my crazy already.

Thanks!!

Luciano

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange bug. I solved this problem by adding this line to the showDIV function:

```
$('#'+winname+' iframe').attr('src','http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html');
```

Comment: Actually, this works but it seems to do some kind of session closing on http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html. We use a different page instead of this one which handles session and it seems to be like closing and reopening the page (not really displaying the DIV back again). Any ideas?

Comment: do you need the space of the hidden div?
alternativly you could make the div invisible. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3QjWx/1/ it's working in IE 10

Comment: It worked perfectely with $('#'+winname).contents().find('#chat').attr('src', $('#'+winname).contents().find('#chat').attr('src'));